# text-align right padding right li not working?

Tags: css

```
ul {list-style-type: none;margin:0; padding:0;}
.hits {
  background-image:url(hits.gif); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  float:left;
  width:45px;
  height: 18px; 
  line-height:18px;
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:4px;
 }

<ul>
<li class="hits">328</li>
<li class="hits">0</li>
</ul>
```

p/s hits.gif is 45 px width

Why the text inside li tags is not padded? I tried almost everything.

```
ul {padding:0;}
```

Is it because of this?

Comment: It sure is padded for me. http://jsfiddle.net/5txR9/ What browser are you using?

Comment: There is right padding that can be adjusted. http://jsfiddle.net/85ALe/ Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Filip, it doesnt, I m on Fifefox 8

Comment: Do you use any kind of reset.css?

Comment: BNL, on that page when I change 20px to 5px, nothing changes.

Comment: I figured what it is, if you add a background to li, then the text doesnt move? But if I add a border instead of background  - it moves! strange, I edited the Q

Comment: the solution is to add    background-position:right; but then the li tag gets wider on 4px with background on the right and space on the left...